# travis setup heroku command on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, ruby, windows, heroku, travis-ci

Hi there I'm trying to deploy my  python app using Travis CI but I'm running into problems when I run the "travis setup heroku" command in the cmd prompt.

I'm in my project's root directory, there is an existing ".travis.yml" file in that root directory.

I've also installed ruby correctly and travis correcty because when I run:

- "ruby -v" I get "ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]"
- "travis -v" I get "1.7.7"

When I run "travis setup heroku" I get this message "The system cannot find the path specified" then prompts me for a "Heroku API token:"

What's the issue?

Comment: Do you have heroku toolbelt on your machine?

Comment: Yes I have heroku toolbelt as well

Comment: That seems strange. What happens if you type `heroku auth:token`, does it return a long string of letters and numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you hadn't had Heroku Toolbelt setup to the $PATH environment variable during installation, here are some steps to check:

- Check if Heroku toolbelt is set in PATH variable. If not, cd to your Heroku toolbelt installation folder, then click on the address bar and copy it.
- Go to the Control Panel, then click System and Advanced System Protection.
- Go to Environment Variables, then look for $PATH in the System Variables
- After the last program in the variable, put a `;` then paste in your Heroku CLI folder and click OK. (This requires `cmd` to be restarted manually)
- Login to Heroku CLI
- grab the token key from `heroku auth:token`
- run `travis setup heroku` if the setup goes smoothly, you shouldn't get the command not found and prompt you for heroku auth key. It will ask that you want to encrypt the auth key (highly recommend) and verify the information you provided with the toolbelt and Travis CLI.
- commit changes
- you should be able to get your app up and running within your tests.